# Updating when running off USB stick makes it unbootable?

Tags: 10.10, update-manager, usb-drive, initramfs

I guess one should not run the software update when running off of a pendrive. Each time I have, not only does the update crash, but the usb drive becomes unbootable? Should the ablitiy to run a software update be disabled for pendrive instances?

Comment: You tagged this initramfs, are you getting a particular error?

Comment: Did you try it on pen drives other than the one this problem occurred on?

Comment: Sorry, I gave up and just went for it! Turned out the installed version went fine.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a problem updating your install as normal. So no the ability shouldn't be disabled.

If you are having problems with this I suggest reporting a bug. Whilst running Ubuntu press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ubuntu-bug`. This will attach harware information to your report.

Comment: Thank you. Although I didn't have an opportunity before, I appreciate the info on how to report a bug with hw info. Cheers.